# ASP.net Button with CssClass not working

Tags: asp.net, css

Problem:

I have two ASP.net `Buttons` that work fine in the Chrome and Firefox browser but not in IE 9.0.

```
*Does not work on IE 9.0*
<asp:Button ID="btnMeal" runat="server" onclick="btnMeal_Click" Text="." CssClass="buttonmeal" />

*Works fine on IE 9.0 and other browsers*
<asp:Button ID="btnType" runat="server" onclick="btnType_Click" Text="." CssClass="button"/>
```

CSS Code:

```
/*Doesnt work*/
.buttonmeal
 {
        background: url('../images/meal.png') no-repeat;
        width:82px;
        height:32px;
        border:0px;     
    }

/*Works*/
    .button
    {
        background: url('../images/type.png') no-repeat;
        width:82px;
        height:32px;
        border:0px;     
    }
```

Maybe I think the problem is because it renders in IE differently and only button is used in IE.

```
<td class="myStyle">
    <input type="button" name="select" ...>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you done a hard refresh in IE to make sure it is getting the proper CSS?  You might also use the IE developer tools (F12) to inspect the elements to see what's going on.

Comment: the only difference between your buttons is end tag with space ` />` before `btnMeal` and end tag `/>` with no space before `btnType`

Comment: Hard refresh in IE fixed it. Thank you fellas.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a caching issue (it was for me anyway). There's a good change your browser is not using the newest version of your CSS file. Try a hard refresh:

**Chrome / IE / Firefox**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>